# Issue configuring PhpStorm for JavaScript debugging

Tags: phpstorm, javascript-debugger

I am trying to run JavaScript debugging from PhpStorm.

When I specify `google-chrome` as path in the browsers configuration:

[image: browser configuration]

I get the following error:

```
Cannot run program "google-chrome": error=2, Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Specify full path to your Google Chrome executable?..

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your reply. Specifying the full path to Chrome results in the same error: `Cannot run program "/usr/bin/google-chrome": error=2, Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` Any other idea?

Comment: 1) Is such file is actually there? 2) What about access permissions? 3) On Windows I could say: "try launching PhpStorm as Administrator. Any difference?". But here on Linux ... not sure. 4) How did you install PhpStorm? Is that some flatpack or alike? If it's one of them, try using JetBrains Toolbox or install from ordinary archive: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=linux

Comment: Hello @LazyOne. I used the link you kindly provided and debugging now works fine. Thanks a lot!